# Custom sort list of dictionaries by other dictionary or list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I would like to order based on an external ordering (list, dictionary, whatever works). Let's say I have the following list:

```
list_a = [{"dylan": "alice"}, {"arnie": "charles"}, {"chelsea": "bob"}]
```

and I want to sort it like this

```
sorted_list_a = [{"arnie": "charles"}, {"chelsea": "bob"}, {"dylan": "alice"}]
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
# list_a will have a variable number of dictionaries all with unique keys
# list_order will have all dictionary keys ordered, even if they don't appear in list_a
list_order = [{"arnie": 1}, {"britta": 2}, {"chelsea": 3}, {"dylan": 4}]
list_a.sort(key=lambda x: list_order[x.keys()])
```

but I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict_keys`. I feel like I'm close, but I can't quite get to the end.

Comment: Is your question "Given a key-value pair ``x`` as a dictionary, how do I get the key?"?

Comment: @Asocia what if more than one key?

Comment: @deadshot I asked specifically for only one key-value pair but nevermind, I figured it out lol :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def fun(x):
    k, = (x)
    for d in list_order:
        if k in d:
            return d[k]

res = sorted(list_a, key=fun)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'arnie': 'charles'}, {'chelsea': 'bob'}, {'dylan': 'alice'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  l = [{"dylan": "alice"}, {"arnie": "charles"}, {"chelsea": "bob"}]
d={}
for i in l:
    for x,y in (i.items()):
       d[x]=y
print(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Comment: You're ignoring the list to sort (`list_a`).

Comment: edited please check the output, if it looks good,upvote

Comment: Now it's the data from `list_a`, wrongly called `list_order`, and ignoring the data from the real `list_order`. You're joking, right? :-)

Comment: I havent seen list name ,I saw the output 
sorted_list_a = [{"arnie": "charles"}, {"chelsea": "bob"}, {"dylan": "alice"}] and matched it with my output